# Thymeleaf: append to html element / avoiding repetitive iteration

Tags: html, loops, iteration, thymeleaf

I'm looking for a way to dynamically append html elements to other html elements using Thymeleaf.

Consider the following:

```
<ol class="ol1" />
<ol class="ol2" />
<ol class="ol3" />

<iterate th:each="model">
  <!-- ol1.append(model.name) -->
  <!-- ol2.append(model.type) -->
  <!-- ol3.append(model.something) -->
</iterate>
```

I know that a possible solution would be to have 3 loops, one nested in each of the `<ol>` tags like so:

```
<ol class="ol1">
  <iterate  th:each="model">
    model.name
  </iterate>
</ol>
<ol class="ol2">
  <iterate  th:each="model">
    model.type
  </iterate>
</ol>
<ol class="ol3">
  <iterate  th:each="model">
    model.something
  </iterate>
</ol>
```

This above solution is too inefficient for my liking.

*So, does Thymeleaf provide the functionality to perform only one iteration in this situation?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there's no simpler or more efficient way to do it. I started to think about other ways to get this accomplished, and none were better than the three loops you are using in your question.

Comment: Did your research of other ways include extending Thymeleaf core API to allow for custom dialects that can call custom java functions? I haven't found a way to do this but I feel like it should be possible.

Comment: You can probably accomplish this with templates. See http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/extendingthymeleaf.html#scenario-3-creating-your-own-template-system. I don't have experience with them, so I can't assist further. It's unclear what kind of "inefficiencies" you're trying to eliminate here.  I assumed it was development effort, but, seeing the effort you're interested in pouring into this, that may not be your goal. I believe any processing efficiencies gained would be negligible.

Comment: Also, be aware that Thymeleaf 3 uses a new dialect/processor system, so any custom work may need to be migrated, assuming you'll upgrade when it's released.  See https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/401

Comment: Yes especially development effort. Because there's 1000s of Thymeleaf files in the codebase, something like this would decrease future time spent significantly. Thanks for the clarification.